# Launching specific sections of the Control Panel from the command line

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-explorer, control-panel

I am writing a personal application using AutoHotkey to speed up common tasks. One thing I do often is change my desktop background to solid white (for screenshots I post on Super User, as you may have noticed). My current approach is the following:

1. Run `control`
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
3. Enter `path`

Where `path` is something like:

```
Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Personalization\Desktop Background
```

This is not a bad solution, but I'm curious to know if it's possible to bypass 'typing' in a path and go directly to any specific section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:** Found more information on the topic.

You can use the following to get to the wallpaper screen:

```
control /name Microsoft.Personalization /page pageWallpaper
```

There's a lot of information on this page: [Executing Control Panel Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144191(v=vs.85).aspx)

Here's a list of Control Panel commands for Windows XP taken from [Microsoft Help and Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192806).  Most, if not all of these still work in Windows 7.  Add `,,x` to get to a specific tab, where `x` is a number.

```
Control panel tool             Command
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Accessibility Options          control access.cpl
Add New Hardware               control sysdm.cpl add new hardware
Add/Remove Programs            control appwiz.cpl
Date/Time Properties           control timedate.cpl
Display Properties             control desk.cpl
FindFast                       control findfast.cpl
Fonts Folder                   control fonts
Internet Properties            control inetcpl.cpl
Joystick Properties            control joy.cpl
Keyboard Properties            control main.cpl keyboard
Microsoft Exchange             control mlcfg32.cpl
   (or Windows Messaging)
Microsoft Mail Post Office     control wgpocpl.cpl
Modem Properties               control modem.cpl
Mouse Properties               control main.cpl
Multimedia Properties          control mmsys.cpl
Network Properties             control netcpl.cpl
                               NOTE: In Windows NT 4.0, Network
                               properties is Ncpa.cpl, not Netcpl.cpl
Password Properties            control password.cpl
PC Card                        control main.cpl pc card (PCMCIA)
Power Management (Windows 95)  control main.cpl power
Power Management (Windows 98)  control powercfg.cpl
Printers Folder                control printers
Regional Settings              control intl.cpl
Scanners and Cameras           control sticpl.cpl
Sound Properties               control mmsys.cpl sounds
System Properties              control sysdm.cpl
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for finding even more information.

Answer (score 0):

Network and Sharing Center

```
control /name Microsoft.NetworkAndSharingCenter
```

Network Connections

```
control netconnections
```